# entity framework to a list<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

i use entity framework and have the below code:

```
public class AdvPackageInfo
{
    private int PackageId;
    private string Caption;
    private int Duration;
    private int Count;
    private bool Enable;
    private float Price;
}


 AdvertismentAgancyEntities enn = new AdvertismentAgancyEntities();

 List<AdvPackageInfo> lst = (from s in enn.Tbl_AdvPackage select new AdvPackageInfo { }).ToList();

    repeater1.DataSource = lst;
    repeater1.DataBind();
```

but it works just 1 time and when my page load for the second time it fails in execution and raise NullReferenceException...!!

according to this pag : 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/663200/linq-to-entities-throws-nullreferenceexception-when-the-output-attribute-set-is-empty
it's dot net framework problem.

i try this code too :

var q = (from s in enn.AdvPackage select s).toList();

but it doesn't work either.

is there any better way to make a linq select to a list????

Comment: Isn't it possible that enn.Tbl_AdvPackage is null in the second call? (I'm trying to rule out the more plausible causes first)

Comment: Would be good if you could tell us, which variable is NULL!

Comment: Can you paste the code inside your page? I think the problem is not entity framework but what append in your page after executing query. You use the same object? Are you disposing components after query execution?

Comment: @SmartK8 : from first time to second time nothing change. by second time i means when i refresh the page.

Comment: @sprinter252 : i don't know which variable. it said just " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" nothing more.

Comment: As a side-issue - you are not seriously using a float for "price" are you?

Comment: @Frans while that was a good pick-up (vote-up), please be specific http://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/201648.

Comment: @maryammohammadi Which is nothing but saying that something is null. If you debug your code and hover over some variables one of them supposed to be null. Would be good to know, which.

Comment: @aaron, sorry it was late at night :) thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
List<AdvPackageInfo> lst = 
    (from s in enn.Tbl_AdvPackage select new AdvPackageInfo { }).ToList();
```

You could do this:

```
var lst = new List<AdvPackageInfo>();
for (int i = 0; i < enn.Tbl_AdvPackage.Count(); i++)
    lst.Add(new AdvPackageInfo());
```

(Note that the suggested workaround in the MS Connect page is wrong. Using `Enumerable.Repeat` will create a list full of references to a *single* object)

---

**Update per comment below:**
If you're just trying to load the datagrid, then you just need to retrieve the list as:

```
var lst = enn.Tbl_AdvPackage.ToList();
```

Comment: thank u. it works for the error but there is another problem now! it returns empty records. i mean although there is 5 records of data it returns 5 empty records. i see 5 empty records in grid!!

Comment: Then you haven't stated what you're trying to do very clearly. You're actually trying to just load the records, not create an empty object object for each record. Please see the update.